# Probability that the sum of the two rolls is $4$ given that the first roll is not a $1$

Tags: probability

You roll two six-sided dice, one then the other.

A = {The first roll is a 1}
B = {The sum of the two dice is 4}

What is the value of $P(A^c | B)$?

$A^c$ = $5/6$

B =$1/12$

I thought that the formula would be:

$$1/12 * 5/6 \div 1/12$$

but the result is 10, which is wrong

Comment: Did you mean $P(A^C) = \frac{5}{6}$?

Comment: Yes. sorry I'll edit that.

Comment: what formula are you using? Bayes rule?

Comment: P(B∣A)=P(A∩B)P(A)

Comment: Btw, the correct answer to the *wrong* formula you used is $\frac1{12}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have correctly found that $P(A^C) = \frac{5}{6}$ and that $P(B) = \frac{1}{12}$.  The conditional probability that event $A^C$ occurs given that event $B$ occurs is 
$$P(A^C \mid B) = \frac{P(A^C \cap B)}{P(B)}$$
There are three ways for event $B$ to occur:  (1, 3), (2, 2), (3, 1).  Of these, two do not involve rolling a 1 on the first roll.  Since there are $36$ ordered pairs of rolls in the sample space, 
$$P(A^C \cap B) = \frac{2}{36} = \frac{1}{18}$$
Hence, 
$$P(A^C \mid B) = \frac{P(A^C \cap B)}{P(B)} = \frac{\frac{1}{18}}{\frac{1}{12}} = \frac{2}{3}$$